# css inset box shadow top,left,right, image at bottom

Tags: css, insets

I need to have box shadow on top, right, and left and an image at the bottom. I tried like this:

```
container
  child-container
```

giving the top inset show to the container:

```
box-shadow: 0 5px 5px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) inset;
padding: 8px 0 6px;
background: url("../bottom_image.gif") no-repeat scroll center bottom #FFFCD8;
```

and to the child, give right and left inset shadow:

```
box-shadow: 5px 0 5px -5px #999999 inset, -5px 0 5px -5px #999999 inset;
padding: 0 25px;
```

But there is a line mentioned at the top of the child container.

Can anyone tell me proper way to do it?

Comment: Can you help us understand your goal a little bit better (e.g. examples)

Comment: html example would be extremely helpful

Answer (score 0, accepted):

try this:

[jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/Qw5wT/1/)

```
.container {
    box-shadow: 0 4px 3px 3px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.23) inset;
    padding:8px 25px 0;
    background: url("../bottom_image.gif") no-repeat scroll center bottom #FFFCD8;
}

<div class="container">
    <div class="child-container">FooBar</div>
</div>
```

Comment: thanks @Oldcode101. It works really good, just need to amend the image a bit to cover the image left and right corners.